# ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: JSON simple_form_for

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I've spend a day and a half searching through all of the similar questions but none of them solve my current issue.

I have a simple form, which renders a javascript form, and I'm getting:
**ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: referral):**
whenever I try to submit the form. I've tried using fetch instead of require in my params, but that doesn't fix it (it doesn't log the error but it doesn't save anything either).

I have tried everything I can think of and am at a loss. I used a legacy code example to set up the form, so it's essentially exactly the same format as a form which does work, so I really don't know what I'm missing.

I render the form in a partial, so within my views I have:

**views/homeowners/dashboard/show.html.erb**

```
<%= render "homeowners/dashboard/referrals" %>

<div class="refer-resident-form hidden">
  <%= render 'referral_form' %>
</div>
```

**views/homeowners/dashboard/referrals.html.erb**

```
<div class="card article branded-border">
  <div class="refer-overlay">
    <div class="card-content refer-summary">
      <p class="larger"><%= t(".refer_developer") %></p>
      <p><%= t(".refer_description") %></p>
      <div class="refer-button">
      <%= button_tag t(".refer"), class: "btn branded-btn refer-resident",
      data: { cancel: t("edit.cancel"),
            cta: t(".send_invitation"),
            title: t(".refer")} %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**views/homeowners/dashboard/_referral_form.html.erb**

```
<div class="refer-description">
  <h4><%= t(".refer_description") %> </h4>
</div>

<%= simple_form_for @referral, url: homeowner_dashboard_path, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :referee_first_name, label: t(".first_name"), required: true %>
  <%= f.input :referee_last_name, label: t(".last_name"), required: true %>
  <%= f.input :referee_email, label: t(".email"), required: true %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :referrer_name, value: (current_resident.first_name + " " + current_resident.last_name) %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :referrer_email, value: current_resident.email %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :referral_date, value: Time.now %>
<% end %>
```

My controller **controllers/homeowners/referrals_controller.rb**

```
module Homeowners
  class ReferralsController < Homeowners::BaseController

    def create
      create_new_referral
    end

    private

    def create_new_referral
      @referral = Referral.new(referral_params)
      redirect_to root_path
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def referral_params
      params.require(:referral).permit(
        :referee_first_name, :referee_last_name, :referee_email, :referral_date,
        :referrer_name, :referrer_email
      )
    end
  end
end
```

And my javascript file **refer.js** (please bear in mind I know nothing about javascript and essentially copied this code from a different form, just making minor adjustments to make it relevant)

```
(function (document, $) {
  'use strict'

  $(document).on('click', '.refer-resident', function (event) {
    var dataIn = $(this).data()

    var $referContainer = $('.refer-resident-form')

    $('body').append($referContainer)
    var $form = $('.refer_resident')

    $referContainer.dialog({
      show: 'show',
      modal: true,
      width: 700,
      title: dataIn.title,
      buttons: [
        {
          text: dataIn.cancel,
          class: 'btn',
          click: function () {
            $(this).dialog('destroy')
          }
        },
        {
          text: dataIn.cta,
          class: 'btn-send btn',
          id: 'btn_submit',
          click: function () {
            // Clear any old messages before the post
            $('.flash').empty()

            $.post({
              url: '/homeowners/referral',
              data: $form.serialize(),
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function (response) {
                var $responseP = document.createElement('p')
                if (response.alert === null) {
                  $responseP.className = 'notice'
                  $responseP.innerHTML = response.notice
                } else {
                  // If there are both alert and notice responses, only show the alert
                  $responseP.className = 'alert'
                  $responseP.innerHTML = response.alert
                }
                $('.flash').append($responseP)
                $(window).scrollTop(0)
              }
            })
            $(this).dialog('destroy')
            $referContainer.hide()
          }
        }]
    }).prev().find('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').hide() // Hide the standard close button

    validateSendReferral()
  })

  $(document).on('input', '.refer-resident-form', function (event) {
    validateSendReferral()
  })

  function validateSendReferral () {
    if (($('input#referral_referee_first_name').val().length > 0)
        && ($('input#referral_referee_last_name').val().length > 0) && validateEmail()) {
      $('.btn-send').prop('disabled', false)
      $('.btn-send').removeClass('ui-state-disabled')
    } else {
      $('.btn-send').prop('disabled', true)
      $('.btn-send').addClass('ui-state-disabled')
    }
  }

  function validateEmail () {
    var re = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/
    return re.test($('input.email').val())
  }

})(document, window.jQuery)
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong or what I'm missing please?

**Edit:**

When I submit the form I get the following output

```
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
Started POST "/homeowners/referral" for ::1 at 2019-04-01 12:40:41 +0100
Processing by Homeowners::ReferralsController#create as JSON
  Resident Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "residents".* FROM "residents" WHERE "residents"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "residents"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "resident_notifications" WHERE "resident_notifications"."resident_id" = $1 AND "resident_notifications"."read_at" IS NULL  [["resident_id", 2]]
  Plot Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "plots".* FROM "plots" WHERE "plots"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "plots"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Developer Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "developers".* FROM "developers" WHERE "developers"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "developers"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Country Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "countries".* FROM "countries" WHERE "countries"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Development Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "developments".* FROM "developments" WHERE "developments"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "developments"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Brand Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "brands".* FROM "brands" WHERE "brands"."brandable_id" = $1 AND "brands"."brandable_type" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["brandable_id", 1], ["brandable_type", "Development"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 400 Bad Request in 24ms (ActiveRecord: 3.1ms)



ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: referral):

app/controllers/homeowners/referrals_controller.rb:23:in `referral_params'
app/controllers/homeowners/referrals_controller.rb:17:in `create_new_referral'
app/controllers/homeowners/referrals_controller.rb:11:in `create'
```

Comment: It looks like a problem with passing params from form to the controller. Can you please update your question with logs for the request that creates new referral?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're trying to serialize the form with a jQuery selector that may not be actually targeting the form. Specifically, you're calling

```js
var $form = $('.refer_resident')
```

and then

```js
$.post({
  ...
  data: $form.serialize(),
```

but I don't see that you're giving the form that class specifically, and I don't think simple_form will generate that class for you. I believe it will generate classes like `.new_referral` and `.edit_referral` based on the presence of an id attribute. You can either explicitly assign that class or just use the built-in class.

Comment: Thank you, the JavaScript turned out to be the issue. I was targeting the wrong container. I have my params passing through now, just not saving to the database. Hopefully that one will be easier to figure out.